# Computing specific Clebsch-Gordan coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space

I am trying to compute some Clebsch-Gordan coefficients with some specific values. My coefficients look like

$$
\left< L,0;1,\lambda\middle|J,M\right>
$$

I know that $M=0+\lambda=\lambda$ and that $J$ ranges from $|L-1|$ to $L+1$, so that I have three cases: $J=L-1$, $J=L$, and $J=L+1$. For instance, if I take the second case, I have

$$
\left< L,0;1,\lambda\middle|L,\lambda\right>
$$

I know that the answer should be

$$
-\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2}},~\lambda=-1,0,+1
$$

However, I cannot get the expression myself. I was thinking of using the recursion relation given for Clebsch-Gordan, for instance in Sakurai, which is

$$
\sqrt{(J\mp M)(J\pm M+1)}\left< L,M_L;1,\lambda\middle|J,M\pm1\right> = \sqrt{(L\mp M_L)(L\pm M_L+1)}\left< L,M_L\mp1;1,\lambda\middle|J,M\right>+\sqrt{(1\mp \lambda)(1\pm \lambda+1)}\left< L,M_L;1,\lambda\mp1\middle|J,M\right>
$$

For $J=L$, $M=\lambda$, this becomes

$$
\sqrt{(J\mp \lambda)(J\pm \lambda+1)}\left< J,0;1,\lambda\middle|J,\lambda\pm1\right> = \sqrt{J(J+1)}\left< J,\mp1;1,\lambda\middle|J,\lambda\right>+\sqrt{(1\mp \lambda)(2\pm \lambda)}\left< J,0;1,\lambda\mp1\middle|J,\lambda\right>
$$

but now I am at loss, since none of the coefficients looks like my original coefficient. What am I doing wrong? Is there another method to compute these functions?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There's various open-source software for this, e.g., https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/quantum/cg.html . Is that all you want, the ability to calculate specific CG coefficients numerically?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am looking for a way to compute them using known recursion relations or identities, without relying on software. I would like to understand how to approach the problem generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an *almost* solution, based on symmetry relations between the CGs.

One has quite genrally
\begin{align}
\langle \ell_1m_1;\ell_2 m_2\vert LM\rangle = 
\sqrt{\frac{2L+1}{2\ell_1+1}}(-1)^{\ell_2+m_2}
\langle L,-M ;\ell_2 m_2\vert \ell_1 -m_1\rangle
\end{align}
so set $\ell_2=1$ and $m_2=0$.  Now, if $m_1=m_2=M=0$, then
one obtains, with $\ell_1=L$: 
\begin{align}
\langle L 0;10\vert L 0\rangle = (-1)\langle L 0;10\vert L 0\rangle
\end{align}
so that this one is $0$.  Next, use this again with $m_2=M\ne 0$ but with $m_1=0$ to find
\begin{align}
\langle L 0;1M\vert LM\rangle = 
(-1)^{1-M}\langle L,-M ;1M\vert L0\rangle\, .
\end{align}
The CGs must satisfy
\begin{align}
\sum_{m_2(M)} \vert \langle L,-M;1M\vert L0\rangle\vert^2=1 
\end{align}
and using $\langle L,-M;1 M\vert L0\rangle = (-1)\langle L M;1,-M\vert L0\rangle$ you can see that:

1. For $M=0$ the CG is $0$ as discussed before,
2. For $M=1$ the CG is in absolute value the same as for $M=-1$.

   As they must all sum to $1$ you can conclude that one is $+1/\sqrt{2}$ while the other is $-1/\sqrt{2}$.

I'm not quite sure how to get the phase: I thought of starting from the Condon-Shortley convention $\langle 1,1;L,L-1\vert L,L\rangle >0$ but I don't quite see how to get it down to 
$\langle 1,1;L 0\vert L, 1\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is probably what I need. I will try to apply it to the cases $J=L-1,~L+1$ as well, and see what I get.