# Usage in the Clebsch-Gordan (CG) coefficients' recursive relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum

In Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics, its 3.8.39 is
\begin{aligned}\sqrt{(j\mp m)(j\pm m+1)}\langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2|j_1j_2;j,m\pm1 \rangle \\=\sqrt{(j_1\mp m_1+1)(j_1\pm m_1)}\langle  j_1j_2;m_1\mp1,m_2|j_1j_2;jm\rangle\\\quad+\sqrt{(j_2\mp m_2+1)(j_2\pm m_2)}\langle j_1j_2;m_1,m_2\mp1|j_1j_2;jm\rangle,  ~~~ (3.369) \end{aligned}
and need $m_1 + m_2 = m \pm 1$, (3.370).

However, in 3.8.54, they choose $ m_1 = m_l, m_2 = 1/2 ,j_1 = l, j_2 = 1/2, j=l+1/2 $. And $ m_1 + m_2 = m $
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{\left(l+\frac12+m+1\right)\left(l+\frac12-m\right)}\left\langle m-\frac12,\frac12|l+\frac12,m\right\rangle  \\
=\sqrt{\left(l+m+\frac12\right)\left(l-m-\frac12\right)}\left\langle m+\frac12,\frac12|l+\frac12,m+1\right\rangle , ~~~ (3.374)
\end{aligned}
choosing the lower sign of 3.8.39.

But why, in there, $ m_1 + m_2 = m \neq m-1 $?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/790080/regarding-clebsch-gordan-coefficients-using-recursive-method), and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/504220/computing-specific-clebsch-gordan-coefficients).

Comment: Hopefully, you appreciate that the *m* utilized in (3.369,3.370) is not the same *m'* of (3.374), so *m'=m-1*. Wish to withdraw the question?